# Bind function with self in single line in Lua

Tags: lua

I would like to have a function pointer (don't know what the term is in Lua) that has the self pointer baked in.

A concept example

```lua
x = {text = "hello there"}

function x.hello(self)
    print(self.text)
end

--- This is where I'm stuck

function_pointer = ???

function_pointer() -- Expected behaviour is to call x:hello() but how
```

Is there any way possible to bake the self pointer into a function (pointer)? Like that?

Comment: Use `fp = function () return x:hello() end`

Answer (score 1):

Another (easy/lazy) way is to construct the table itself as a function for its content.
This is done with `setmetatable()` and the `__call` Metamethod.

```
x = setmetatable({text = "Hello there"}, {__call = function(self) print(self.text) end})

x() -- Hello there
-- A pointer will be...
fp = getmetatable(x).__call

fp(x) -- Hello There
```

PS: You are totally free to choose the Name for `self`

```
x = setmetatable({text = "Hello there"}, {__call = function(this) print(this.text) end})
```

...especially the 'Basic People' will using `this` ;-)
It is only the first Element in the Chain of Arguments...

```
local func = function(...) print(({...})[1].text) end -- Anonymous "self"
x = setmetatable({text = "Hello there"}, {__call = func})
```